# In a plugin, how to get entry status?

Tags: plugin-development, database

This seems like it should be simple to find, but where does Craft store the *status* of **entries** (lightswitch for enabled/disabled)?  It doesn't seem to be a column in the entries table, and I can't figure out how the other tables are linked to the entry number.

Background: In a plug-in, I'm trying to filter a query to exclude only those that are disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference, the status of all elements is stored in the "elements" table, the column is "enabled" and the valid values are 1 and 0. Entry, Category, Matrix, Asset and all other elements will have their id as a foreign key linked to this table

Comment: Ah, OK, so it looks like the id in the "entries" table is the same as the id in the "elements" table. That leaves me with:         `$cal->occurrences = (new Query()) ->select('*') ->from("myTable") ->leftJoin('craft_elements', 'myTable.event_id = craft_elements.id') ->Where("craft_elements.enabled = '1'") ->andWhere(...)->all();`  which works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Is this Craft 2 or Craft 3?

There are a few of ways to get entries but basically you could do something like (Craft 3)

```
use craft\elements\Entry;

$entries = Entry::find()->status(null)->all();
```

To find all disabled entries.

Comment: Thank you. Craft 3. I was hoping for something I could use in a `query->leftjoin('craft_entries', 'otherTable.entry_id = craft_entries.id')` sort of thing, but I suppose this info will work with a for loop to clear out the disabled ones.